# Python C API ImportError "most likely due to a circular import"

Tags: c, nltk, nasm

The C code shown below uses the Python C API to import the NLTK library on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.8.  It's linked into a NASM program that calls Lib_Gutenberg.  My ultimate purpose is to import the Gutenberg corpus.  I pass two different module names, nltk and nltk.corpus.gutenberg, but in both cases I get exactly the same error:  "ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter' from partially initialized module 'collections' (most likely due to a circular import)."

The full error message from PyErr_Print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 102,   in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 10,   in <module>
    import fnmatch
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/fnmatch.py", line 14, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 125, in <module>
    import functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 17, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/collections.py", line     11, in <module>
    from collections import Counter, defaultdict, deque
ImportError: cannot import name 'Counter' from partially initialized module 'collections' (most likely due to a circular import) /home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/collections.py)
```

The C code to import the nltk library (NLTK_Gutenberg_C.c):

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int Lib_Gutenberg(char* module_name)
{

    PyObject *pName, *pModule;

    wchar_t * syspath = L"/home/txqcusr /.local/lib/python3.8:/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/:/home/txqcusr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk:/usr/lib/python3.8";

    Py_Initialize();
    int pii = Py_IsInitialized();

    PySys_SetPath(syspath);

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(module_name);

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule == 0x0){
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1; }

    return 0;
}
```

The NASM wrapper that calls it (NLTK_Gutenberg.asm):

```
; Header Section
[BITS 64]

[default rel]

global Main_Entry_fn
global NLTK_Gutenberg_fn
extern Lib_Gutenberg

section .data align=64

section .rodata align=64
module_name: db 'nltk',0x00

section .text

Main_Entry_fn:

push rdi
push rbp
push rbx

lea rdi,[module_name]
call [rel Lib_Gutenberg wrt ..got]

NLTK_Gutenberg_fn:
mov rax,0
mov rbx,0

pop rbx
pop rbp
pop rdi
ret
```

So the issue is a "most likely due to a circular import" but I don't know how to fix that when calling from the Python C API.  When I include "import nltk" in a Python program on the same server it works with no problem.

I also tried PyImport_ImportModule but got the same error message, and I tried this:

```
const char *str_command = "import nltk";
PyRun_SimpleString(str_command);
```

but got the same error message.

Some other Stack Overflow threads have suggested to reinstall the library, but the import works when called from Python, so the library is correctly installed.

Compile C:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -ggdb -lpython3.8 -o NLTK_Gutenberg_C_Small2.o NLTK_Gutenberg_C_Small2.c -lpython3.8 -I/usr/include/python3.8 -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -Wall -Wextra
```

Assemble and link NASM:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf NLTK_Gutenberg.asm
ld -shared NLTK_Gutenberg.o /opt/P01_SH/NLTK_Gutenberg/NLTK_Gutenberg_C_Small2.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Timer_for_NASM.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Create_Threads_in_C-NLTK_Gutenberg.o -lpython3.8 -ldl -lrt -lpthread -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -o NLTK_Gutenberg.so
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to compile code?!

Comment: I use sudo for most things.  I don't bother to think about where I do and don't need to use it.  Its use makes no difference.

Comment: That's a terrible idea, you should stop doing that. Or just work as root if you don't care...